# Validation still saves null fields in DB

Tags: angularjs, validation, controller

I'm a newbie to AngularJS. I need to validate the `fields` so when the user types `empty` information, the error is shown and data still does not save into `DB`. If information is valid then ofcourse it must be saved into my `DB`

The `messages` works fine, however content still gets saved if the user leaves `empty` fields and hits `submit`.

Below is my validation of the `controller`:

```
    app.controller('addContactCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http)    
{
    $scope.newContact = function(contact) {
        $scope.queryMsg= ""; //displays if sent or not in html form
        //post is used to create
        $http.post('model/addContact.php', contact).success(function(data) {
                if (data && contact != "") 
                {//row inserted into table
                  $scope.queryMsg = "Query has been sent successfully.";
                  $scope.contact = "";
                }
                else
                {
                  $scope.queryMsg = "Fields cannot be left empty.";
                }
            })
        };
    }
]);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do your back end do theses verification aswell ?

Comment: What Okazari said, this has to be done in backend as well, DO NOT TRUST ANYONE when it comes to data, even yourself

Answer (score 0):

You might need to validate it before posting the data. You doing validation after post. Please try this

```
    app.controller('addContactCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http)    
     {
       $scope.newContact = function(contact) {
         $scope.queryMsg= ""; //displays if sent or not in html form
         //post is used to create
         if (contact != "") { 
           $http.post('model/addContact.php', contact).success(function(data) {
                if (data){
                  $scope.queryMsg = "Query has been sent successfully.";
                }
            })
         } else {

          $scope.queryMsg = "Fields cannot be left empty.";
         }

        };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would validate on the form.
The submit button will be disabled until the form is valid,  you can use ng-messages to show a message.

you can read more about it https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input ng-model="data" required>
    <input ng-model="contact" required>
    <button ng-disabled myform.$invalid >submit</button>
</form>
```